# Can't set customized property on objects

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to define a customized property called `userdata`, but for objects like location.hash, it doesn't work, I got `false, false` with the two alert calls.

```
        Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "userdata", {
            value: false,
            writable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });

        alert (location.hash.userdata);
        location.hash.userdata = true;
        alert (location.hash.userdata);
```

Is it immutable?

If I define my own object, i.e

```
var a = {};
a.userdata = true;
```

It will be set correctly, I couldn't get why the former example doesn't work

Comment: `location.hash` is a string and not an Object.

Comment: Suggestion @IliaFrenkel ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: as @plalx said, `location.hash` returns a primitive string, not a String object. It's like `"foo".userdata = true`, there is no way you can get the value you've stored in `"foo"` primitive string, because the Object created to access to this property is already discarded. You should read [Distinction between string primitives and String objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects). In addition, extend the `Object.prototype` is **really** a **bad** idea. Especially for *enumerable* props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal that the first alert gives false since the default value for `userdata` is `false`.

However, `location.hash.userdata = true;` will definitely not work because when you treat the `location.hash` primitive string as an object using the dot notation, it will wrap the primitive value in the `String` primitive wrapper and that wrapper object is then discarded after, so it's the same as doing `new String(location.hash).userdata = true;`

Since you cannot do `location.hash = new String(location.hash)`, you will have to store your properties on another object because `location.hash` will always be immutable.